# %%a and %%a with set in brackets (cmd-script)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to make a cmd-windows-backup-script for my four firefox profiles.

But I have a curious problem.

%%c and %%c in the set command have different values.

I think it's because the (...)

Any idea how I can fix this problem?

```
    cd /D "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"

    for /D %%c in (*) do (

        echo %%c            

        set source="%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%%c"
        set target="%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\AutoBackup\%date%\%%c.7z"

        echo %source%
        echo %target%

        rem here is now my zip action planned, but source and target have always the same name

        timeout 5

    )
```

Comment: @SomethingDark doesn't look like a dupe to me.  The OP's problem has nothing to do with delayed expansion.

Comment: @jwdonahue - he's setting variables inside of a code block and then asking why his variable values aren't what he expects them to be. That's the very definition of a delayed expansion problem. He just coincidentally happens to have a second problem that he hasn't found out about yet, which is the answer you posted.

Comment: @SomethingDark, hmm... apologies.  This is why I never use multi-line code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /D "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"

for /D %%c in (*) do (

    echo %%c            

    set source="%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%%c"
    set target="%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\AutoBackup\%date%\%%c.7z"

    echo !source!
    echo !target!
    timeout 5

)
endlocal
```

for more on `delayedexpansion` do from cmdline `setlocal /?`

Comment: oh. thanks. I'm not so often script in cmd (prefer sh/bash ;-)).This was very helpfull. Learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: @marcus did it solve your problem?